# Connect to a MySQL server over SSH in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I'd like to establish an ssh tunnel over ssh to my mysql server.

Ideally I'd return a mysqli db pointer just like I was connecting directly.

I'm on a shared host that doesn't have the [SSH2](http://ca.php.net/ssh2) libraries but I might be able to get them installed locally using PECL.

If there's a way that uses native commands that would be great.

I was thinking something like this, but without those libraries it won't work.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('SERVER IP', 22); 

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, 'DESTINATION IP', 3307);

$db = new mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD', 
                         'dbname', 3307, $tunnel)
    or die ('Fail: ' . mysql_error());
```

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm running a shared CentOS linux host at liquidweb.

Any thoughts on making the tunnel persistent?  Is it possible to establish it with another script and just take advantage of it in `PHP`?

Thanks.

Comment: You realize that everyone else on that shared host will also be able to make connections to your database right?

Comment: It would still require a valid username and password to connect but it's a definite risk.  Would that be the case if the tunnel were created per-execution in php?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer, as I noticed upon reading the documentation that it's a lot more involved than I thought to get mysqli to use SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric,

I think you are out of luck on this one. You can either use the ssh extension in your PHP code, or if you have access to the server, you could try to create a ssh tunnel on the command-line.

You probably need special permissions to do that, though. It also looks like you don't have ssh access to this hosting account.

--Joao

Answer (score 16):

I would use the [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) tool to create a persistent ssh tunnel to your mysql database. Then all you have to do in your PHP code is point it to localhost.

You can test this (without automatic restart) by doing:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@domain.com
```

Setup a ssh key so that you don't need to use passwords, and tweak the .ssh/authorized_keys file on the mysql system to only allow it to be used for port forwarding.

For more info on ssh tricks see [Brian Hatch's](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030228.html) excellent series on SSH and port forwarding.

Comment: This answer got me on the right track. I finally figured it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464317/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php#comment65229024_16138417

Answer (score 13):

The tunnel must be keep open during the course of the SQL action(s). The following example from [RJMetrics](http://blog.rjmetrics.com/PHP-MySQL-and-SSH-Tunneling-Port-Forwarding/) explains:

Here's the generic SSH command syntax:

```
ssh -f -L bind-ip-address:bind-port:remote-ip-address:remote-port \
username@remote-server [command] >> /path/to/logfile
```

Here's how to securely establish a remote database connection in just 2 lines of PHP code:

```
shell_exec("ssh -f -L 127.0.0.1:3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remote.rjmetrics.com sleep 60 >> logfile");  
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "sqluser", "sqlpassword", "rjmadmin", 3307);
```

We use the `shell_exec()` function to create the tunnel with a 60 second opening window, and then use the `mysqli_connect()` function to open a database connection using the forwarded port. Note that we must use the "mysqli" library here because `mysql_connect()` does not allow us to specify a port and `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

`sleep 60`: When it comes to tunnel connections, we basically have two options: leave the connection open all the time or open it and close it as needed. We prefer the latter, and as such we don't specify the `-N` option when establishing a tunnel, which would leave it open until the process is manually killed (bad for automation). Since `-N` is not specified, our tunnel will close itself as soon as its SSH session isn't being used for anything. This is ideal behavior, except for the few seconds between when we create the tunnel and when we get a MySQL connection up and running via the tunnel. To buy us some time during this period, we issue the harmless `sleep 60` command when the tunnel is created, which basically buys us 60 seconds to get something else going through the tunnel before it closes itself. As long as a MySQL connection is established in that timeframe, we are all set.

Comment: This asks for ssh password how to deal with it?

Answer (score 7):

I tried it by doing SSH both by root credentials and and public private key pair. It allows me to conect through command line but not through PHP code.

I also tried by creating a tunnel (by using SSH2 functions), and running shell commands from PHP code (`system`, `exec`, etc.); nothing worked.

Finally I tried SSH2 function to execute shell command and it finally worked :)

Here is my code, if it helps you:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($remotehost, '22');
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user,$pass)) {
    echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
} else {
    die('Authentication Failed...');
}


$stream=ssh2_exec($connection,'echo "select * from zingaya.users where id=\"1606\";"  | mysql');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
while($line = fgets($stream)) {
    flush();
    echo $line."\n";
}
```

Try this if want to use PHP functions specifically.

Answer (score 3):

It *is* possible, but why? It's more complicated than it needs to be, and error prone.

Can you not run the database locally? If not, can you not use something like SQLite, XML files or something else that doesn't require a separate server daemon?

You *really* do not want to initialise the tunnel inside the PHP scripts. Initialising an SSH tunnel takes a long time (can easily be a second or two), so that will mean every page that connects to the database will have a 2 seconds delay while loading..

If you *have* to do this (which I strongly recommend against), the best method would be to have a script that maintains the connection in the background..

Setup a [SSH keypair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication). Then using [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/), or a simple script which would execute the required SSH command, wait till the process died and start it again. It could be more intelligent and try and run a command every 10-20 seconds, reconnecting if it fails.

Using the SSH keypair, you wouldn't have to hardcode the remote users password in the script. I would recommend limiting what the remote user can do (by using a dedicated tunnel user, and giving it a restricted shell, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021/allow-user-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-but-nothing-else) question)

In short, I would strongly suggest trying SQLite first, then see how feasible it to store data using XML files, then try bugging your web-host about getting a local MySQL server, *then* look into the SSH tunnelling option.

Comment: would you recommend SSL over SSH if an encrypted connection is required?

Comment: @ChristopherIckes Yes, SSL would be much more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to find a different hosting provider; I suggest a VPS solution (Virtual Private Server) which gives you full control over your web host. THat way, if you don't like the default configuration, you can upgrade it yourself.