# Laravel 5.2 connect to remote DB via ssh

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, ssh

I am connecting to remote DB via ssh tunnel

Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495364/laravel-mysql-db-connection-with-ssh)

Here are the DBeaver screenshots :

[image]

And

[image]

What i am doing is for the ssh is :

`ssh -i sharp -N -L 13306:127.0.0.1:3306 root@163.182.198.10`

But it says

`Permission denied (publickey).`

What am i missing ?

Answer (score -1):

You're specifying an incorrect public key.

I mean, the error you gave us tells you that.

```
-i identity_file
             Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and
             ~/.ssh/id_rsa.  Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple -i options (and multiple
             identities specified in configuration files).  If no certificates have been explicitly specified by the CertificateFile directive, ssh will also try to load cer-
             tificate information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to identity filenames.
```

Out of curiosity, what's stopping you using this?

https://packagist.org/packages/stechstudio/laravel-ssh-tunnel

ALSO:

If you read the comments you'll find some issues reporting issues with the -N option. Try removing it.

`-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports.`

Comment: I have removed -N before too and not working, My question is that why the above method not working, If dbeaver works with the same method then why its not working on my terminal