# Laravel Create mysql SSH Tunnel on windows10 programmatically?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel, ssh

Trying to setup a local Windows10 environment for Laravel 6 and need to connect with SSH to a remote linux mysql server.

Standard configuration doesnt seem to support a way to connect with SSH tunnels, but I did find a workaround that I need help finishing.

It seems the only way to get the connection going is through port forwarding, which I am able to do with gitbash/windows terminal

```
ssh -i /c/Users/MyUserName/MyKeyFolder/sitemaster_ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 linuxUser@remoteHost.com
```

After running that manually in terminal / gitbash, I am able to use localhost with port 3307 successfully for my database configuration in Laravel and visit my site locally

Ideally, I would like to programatically check this port before laravel tries to access port 3307 on startup as well as some type of detection for later calls and reopen only if necessary.

I used this article which lays out the basics but is unclear as to whether the command line code can only be run manually
or if can be run with a script somewhere, somehow.

[Laravel MySql DB Connection with SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495364/laravel-mysql-db-connection-with-ssh)

I have tried doing things like

```
exec('ssh -i /c/Users/MyUserName/MyKeyFolder/sitemaster_ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 linuxUser@remoteHost.com');
```

as well as putting in its own script nameed port_fwd_3307.sh and then running

```
exec('port_fwd_3307.sh');
```

I can navigate to the sh file from terminal and confirm it runs and the script is calling it from the proper directory, but still, I get no connection and no feedback as to whats going on other than server actively refused (but I know its a port issue, since it resolves successfully when run manually).

I have placed that command in the bootstrap/app.php file, as well as tried it in the config/database.php and public/index.php 
before laravel even starts and none of this works.

Not sure if this is possible at all, but if it is, what specific part of the framework would it need to be located in to ensure the port is forwarded prior to the database connection?