# Connect to mysql in php over ssh?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible (and how so if yes) to connect to a mysql DB over ssh in php?
Before, I would connect to a VPN then just connect normally to the mysql DB normally (this is for local testing purposes only) but that is not working at the moment so my only other option is to use SSH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to a MySQL server over SSH in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464317/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464317/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php) is sort of exatly the same question