PHP connects MySQL over ssh connection
PHP is in Linux Server A;
MySQL is in Linux Server B, only TCP port 22 is opened.
(ServerA IP is 192.168.0.101, ServerB IP is 192.168.0.102, Database name is DBtest , username=usera , passoword=123456;)

How to write a PHP connection string to get data ?
Is there any problem if each db connection establish a SSH tunnel ?
OR
Can I establish SSH connection between Server A and B ? so that I can use simple connection string,
But how to re-establish the SSH connection in case sudden disconnection ?

Anyone can help on this issue ?
Thank you for your answering.

Assuming you have static IPs, I think by far the easiest option is to just open the MySQL port for that specific remote IP. Otherwise, there's a bunch of answers here that you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/q/464317/231316
