# Connect to a mysql database via SSH through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, mysqli, phpseclib

I have already written a php file that connects to the mysql database locally. Now, I want to connect to a remote database via SSH. Currently the connect function for my database is the following in php:

```
$this->db = new mysqli(_SERVR_URL, _SERVR_USER , _SERVR_PASS, _SERVR_DB);
    if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->db->connect_errno . ") " . $this->db->connect_error;
    }
    else{
        //echo "Successfully connected!! <BR><BR>";
    }
```

I want to only change the connect function (above) so that the rest of the code still works. I have successfully installed the phpseclib and am not interested in installing php's ssh extensions because those were not working after nearly 5 hours of effort. The phpseclib is working, and I think this because when I use require it does not die.

However, when I try to start working with the ssh stuff, it throws a server error:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH1(myURL);
```

The way that I usually SSH into my server is with a .pem file. Can I get some guidance on:

1. Why the current code may be throwing an error?
2. If this is possible.
3. How would you write the connection code with the .pem file.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309615/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php

Comment: It is not a duplicate. They did not need to use a .pem file and they did not ask specifically about the phpseclib library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think you are out of luck on this one. You can either use the ssh
>   extension in your PHP code, or if you have access to the server, you
>   could try to create a ssh tunnel on the command-line.
>
> You probably need special permissions to do that, though. It also
>   looks like you don't have ssh access to this hosting account.

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309615/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php) answered by @jpm

[Setting up tunneling](http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html) posted by @Ólafur Waage on [Connect to a MySQL server over SSH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464317/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php)

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464317/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php) for tunneling by @Sosy

```
shell_exec(“ssh -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remote.rjmetrics.com sleep 60 >> logfile”);  
$db = mysqli_connect(’127.0.0.1′, ‘sqluser’, ‘sqlpassword’, ‘rjmadmin’, 3307);
```

Comment: EDIT: just saw your edit.
Thanks for the help with the tunneling - is that actually safe to do?

Comment: However, it could create some vulnerabilities, some system errors that can't be handled in php, it's matter alternatives vs. efforts vs. simplicity

Comment: My php script won't create the ssh tunnel, but when I make it in the terminal, the code will work for the specified time. Any reason why that would happen?

Comment: check if shell_exec is false, check the logfile,  inspect your php conf (safe_mode should be disabled), try maybe system() or exec().

Comment: I have done these things - the stderror I get from the shell exec is: "Could not create directory '/Library/WebServer/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed." I saw several stackoverflow posts about it but I am getting very wary of security flaws. I would be more inclined to accept an answer that had information about what was going on with phpseclib, which is much more secure.

Comment: PHP's mysql extensions can't tunnel through PHP sockets. So unless you have a pure PHP mysql implementation (or want to rewrite the mysql extension) you're (unfortunately) out of luck :(

Answer (score 1):

The mysql extension doesn't currently support this. Modifying the extension, itself, might not be that difficult, but at that point, it'd have to be a custom PECL extension, at best. The idea was discussed on the PHP Internals mailing list a while back:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.devel/79520