# How do you setup SSL to connect to an RDS MySQL Instance

Tags: mysql, security, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

I am new to RDS Instances and Security, I am wondering how I can setup SSL to connect to my MySQL RDS Instance so i can do the following

1. connect to my RDS through SequelPro Application
2. connect via PHP (my framework is laravel)

I looked everywhere and AWS only gives me a rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem key and a rds-ca-2015-{regional-key} i don't even know what to do with these. 
[RDS Bundle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) and MySQL Specific [Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport)

SSL requires a key file, a certificate file and a CA certificate file.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you link to directly specifies how to connect to an RDS instance via SSH:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

```
mysql -h myinstance.c9akciq32.rds-us-east-1.amazonaws.com \
  --ssl-ca=[full path]rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert
```

So the questions now are:

**How to get SequelPro to connect via SSH:**

According to the [SequelPro documentation](https://sequelpro.com/docs/get-started/get-connected/remote), it only can connect via SSH using an SSH tunnel.

So you'll need to connect via SSH from your local computer to an EC2 instance in your VPC. Getting this setup has nothing to do with your RDS instance. Once that connection is established, you would use this tunnel to make a non-SSH connection to your RDS instance.

See: https://sequelpro.com/docs/get-started/get-connected/remote

**Connect to RDS from your PHP app:**

Similarly, it looks like PHP does not have built-in SSH support for MySQL connections.

There are many QA on Stack Overflow on this topic:

- [Connect to a MySQL server over SSH in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464317/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php)
- [Connect to a mysql database via SSH through PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069658/connect-to-a-mysql-database-via-ssh-through-php)

**Conclusion**

In both accounts, it looks like SSH tunnels is the only way to go.  So you either:

- live with the tunnels,
- use standard connection (non-encrypted), or
- use other tools/mechanisms to connect that do support SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the underlying server via SSH on the RDS product. If you absolutely have to have access you will need to install the database on an EC2 instance and forgo the benefits of using RDS

See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=153017

Comment: Not correct. RDS MySQL supports direct SSH connections: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

Comment: The article is for enable SSL connection to the RDS Engine, not SSH!