# Not just another can't connect php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache, redhat

PHP MySQL is not connecting... Here are the specs:
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.39, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
PHP 5.4.33 (cli)
php-mysql for this version is loaded.

Briefing:
This is a fresh Lamp install.
I can connect to the database using SSH commands.
The user I am trying to connect with has all permissions granted to the database I'm connecting to. 
Logging in using SSH with that user password from SSH works fine. I can access the database and select from tables.

When I try and connect from PHP I get cannot login to database.

Additional information:
there is no domain pointing to the server. I have a virtual host setup in apache and I'm using my local host file to act as the DNS to access the server.

Any ideas?

Added:

```
 <?PHP
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "myuser", "mypassword", "mydatabase");
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: This may have been "Asked and Answered" already --see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309615/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php

Comment: Provide code you tried.

Comment: Read and tried every one of the stack overflow answers. Most had to do with either showing how to setup php-mysql which I have done this time and many times before. And the other was just basic connection information for PHP.

Comment: What isn't clear is whether you are connecting from PHP _on the same machine as the MySQL service_ or from a _remote machine_. MySQL uses a combination of user and host to identify users, so `user@localhost` is not the same as `user@some.remote.ip` as far as GRANTs are concerned. That you mention your local hosts file makes me think you're connecting from a remote server.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to troubleshoot your PHP if you don't share your code?

Comment: It's the same machine using localhost

Comment: Ok added code. Sorry I just figured that since I didn't say I was a newbie that you would know that I know how to write the code to connect.

Comment: What about the error? Is it echoing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypassword", "mydatabase");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

if above code does not work then 
try to connect using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
<?php
        $db_host="localhost";
        $db_pass='mypassword'; 
        $db_username="myuser";
        $db_name="mydatabase";
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
        echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

hope this will work. :)