# Creating username and password for MySQL when I don't know where they will be logging in from

Tags: mysql, passwords

I have found these [instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-user-creation/) on how to make usernames and passwords for a MySQL database.  However in the instructions it says that I make the user with the following:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON demo.* TO user1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

However what how do I allow the user to connect from somewhere that isn't a local host.  And in that case does that person's account need to be user1 on this other machine?

Essentially I want to create a username and pass for the database that anyone can use from anywhere

Comment: use `%` for hostname like `user1@%`

Comment: Hmm. Are you making a website? The server should be the one logging in, not the client, so you should know the host location.

Comment: Allowing any IP in the world to connect to your database is **a really bad idea**. That said, rather than reading some really bad blog why not read the documentation?

Comment: @BrianRoach Agreed! Instead, set mySQL access to `localhost` only and use `ssh tunneling` between hosts.  This is not that difficult.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10266397/103081 and change port numbers for mySQL instead of redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%` for hostname part to allow access from any IP like

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%'
GRANT ALL ON demo.* TO username@% IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

But the above method is a bad idea if you don't really need this. You can alternatively specify the IP address Please check this link [Specifying Account Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-names.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the % as a placeholder for unknown hosts.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON demo.* TO user1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```